# Powershell PowerPoint Header

Tags: powershell

I have a simple script that creates a Word Document and a PowerPoint document for staff that are sitting an exam where the files needed are pre loaded to a user area on a file share. The Word Document opens an creates the document header with the line of code

```
$Header = $Section.Headers.Item(1);
$Header.Range.Text = "$FirstName $SecondName $ID Activity 1";
```

PowerPoint is a bit more funnier and when you add a header it asks for dates. Is there a way to do this with powershell? We are printing them afterwards so would be a lot more benificial to have the variables that are in the CSV printed in the header of the document.

If this isn't doable is there a way to edit the first slide to have the variables in the first slide of the PowerPoint.

If anyone is able to look at the code or any ways of simplifying it, it would be massively appreiciated

The CSV is listed below and the full script is at the bottom :)

```
ID  Four    First   Second
219999  9999    Tech    Support
```

Have a good day

```
$Exams = Import-Csv "C:\\techtest.csv"

$fileserver = "C:\\ExamHomes\"

foreach ($User in $Exams)
{
$FirstName = $User.First
$SecondName = $User.Second
$ID = $User.ID
$FourID = $User.Four
$Time = "am"
$Date = "1511"

$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application;
$Word.Visible = $false;
$Doc = $Word.Documents.Add();
$Section = $Doc.Sections.Item(1);
$Header = $Section.Headers.Item(1);
$Header.Range.Text = "$FirstName $SecondName $ID Activity 1";
$Doc.SaveAs("$fileserver\${date}${time}-${FourID}\Desktop\activity 1_${ID}_${FirstName}_${SecondName}.docx");
$Word.Quit()

Write-Host "File 'activity 1_${ID}_${FirstName}_${SecondName}.docx' for $FirstName $SecondName has been created and sent to the folder ${date}${time}-${FourID}" -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Cyan

add-type -assembly microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint
$Application = New-Object -ComObject powerpoint.application
$slideType = "microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.ppSlideLayout" -as [type]
$presentation = $application.Presentations.add()
$presentation.SaveAs("$fileserver\${date}${time}-${FourID}\Desktop\activity 1_${ID}_${FirstName}_${SecondName}.pptx")
$presentation.close()
Stop-Process -name POWERPNT -Force

Write-Host "File 'activity 1_${ID}_${FirstName}_${SecondName}.pptx' for $FirstName $SecondName has been created and sent to the folder ${date}${time}-${FourID}" -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Cyan
}

Write-Host "All Staff have successfully had their document deployed for the exam" -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Red
```

Comment: As aside: you are constantly creating new Word and PowerPoint COM objects **inside** the loop which eventually will gobble up memory and leave weird results. Define these **before** the loop, inside add `$Doc.Close()` and then after the loop `$Word.Quit(); $Application.Quit(); $null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Word); $null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Application); [System.GC]::Collect(); [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()` to clear these objects from memory.

Comment: Can you elaborate on _"when you add a header it asks for dates"_ please?

Comment: Hi Theo, this was in powerpoint itself when you selected add header and footer, it made you select a time only.

As for the Com object I am a little bit lost as I am still navigating my way around PowerShell. :) Thank you for your help I have wondered sometimes as it does slow down towards the end. 

So do you use .Close witin the Loop and then .Quit after the loop so it isn't constantly opening word? and then the 3 release comobjects outside of the loop?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, that's about it. Create Word an PowerPoint objects **before** you enter the loop, only .Close() the Word document (`$Doc.Close()`) and Presentation slide (`$presentation.Close()`) **inside** the loop and .Quit() both Word and PowerPoint **after** the loop finished. Then also do ReleaseComObject... for the 4 COM objects you have used to clear them from memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Headers are only available for [Notes Master and Handout Master objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.headersfooters)
But you can add a Footer on a slide.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint
$Application = New-Object -ComObject powerpoint.application
$presentation = $application.Presentations.add()
$slide = $presentation.Slides.Add(1, [Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout]::ppLayoutTitle)
$slide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "My Title"
$slide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "My SubTitle"
$slide.HeadersFooters.Footer.Visible = $true
$slide.HeadersFooters.Footer.Text = "My Name"
```

You can use some Text on the `DateAndTime` `HeaderFooter` object like this:

```
$slide.HeadersFooters.DateAndTime.Visible = $true
$slide.HeadersFooters.DateAndTime.UseFormat = $true
$slide.HeadersFooters.DateAndTime.Format = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpDateTimeFormat]::ppDateTimeFigureOut
$slide.HeadersFooters.DateAndTime.Text = "Coucou"
```

EDIT: SLIDE MASTER
In fact this can be defined on the `SlideMaster` so that every `Slide` inherit the values from the footer, pagenumber or datetime.
This is defined at the presentation level. So depending what you want do it on the `SlideMaster` or on any `Slide` you create. Probably a `Slide` may override the values from the `SlideMaster`.

```
$presentation.SlideMaster.HeadersFooters.SlideNumber.Visible = $true
$presentation.SlideMaster.HeadersFooters.Footer.Visible = $true
$presentation.SlideMaster.HeadersFooters.Footer.Text = "My Name"

$presentation.SlideMaster.HeadersFooters.DateAndTime.Visible = $true
$presentation.SlideMaster.HeadersFooters.DateAndTime.UseFormat = $true
$presentation.SlideMaster.HeadersFooters.DateAndTime.Format = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpDateTimeFormat]::ppDateTimeFigureOut
$presentation.SlideMaster.HeadersFooters.DateAndTime.Text = "Something"
```

Comment: Perfect, this works as expected and I have adapted it now so it is working, the only problem is after it create the file powerpoint stays open, is there a way to close this?

Comment: Although when I create a second slide on the document it dissappears, is there a powershell line for this to stay on the master slide?

Comment: Add-Type -AssemblyName microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint
$Application = New-Object -ComObject powerpoint.application
$presentation = $application.Presentations.add()
$slide = $presentation.Slides.Add(1, [Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout]::ppLayoutTitle)
$slide.HeadersFooters.Footer.Visible = $true
$slide.HeadersFooters.Footer.Text = "${FirstName}_${SecondName}_UNIT3_AC2&3"
$presentation.SaveAs("$fileserver\ExamHomes\SSCI\${date}${time}\${date}${time}-${FourID}\Desktop\${FirstName}_${SecondName}_UNIT3_AC2&3.pptx")
$presentation.close()

this is the new code now

Comment: `$slide2 = $presentation.Slides.Add(2, [Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout]::ppLayoutBlank)
$presentation.Slides[1].Select()
`
If you speak about the footer, yes I've not found yet how to use a "master" slide. The equivalent of button "Apply to All" button or something like that.